# Cant get rid of filesort in simple query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One for texts and one to assign those texts to categories. I want to select texts of one specific category and order them by last change date. So, I am using this query:

```
SELECT 
     t2.text_id
FROM
    texts_to_categories AS t1,
    texts AS t2
WHERE
    t1.category_id = 123 
    AND t2.text_id = t1.text_id
ORDER BY
    t2.time_changed DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I tried a lot of index combinations but I keep getting a temporary and filesort:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                   key         key_len ref         rows    extra
1   SIMPLE      t1      ref     text_id,text_id_2,category_id   category_id 5       const       203     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      t2      eq_ref  PRIMARY,text_id                 PRIMARY     4       text_id     1       Using where
```

Edit: Here is a CREATE TABLE for the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `texts` (
`text_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`time_changed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`text_id`),
KEY `time_changed` (`time_changed`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=132207 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `texts_to_categories` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`text_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `text_id` (`text_id`,`category_id`),
KEY `text_id_2` (`text_id`),
KEY `category_id` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=740789 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Can you add `show create table ...` for the two tables? The query plan doesn't seem to use any index.

Comment: Okay, I edited my post.

Comment: An index on `(category_id, text_id)` would help your query more than the ones you have. It would also be good if you provided the whole `EXPLAIN` output (and not cut some parts off) so we can see which indexes are used.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add an index on time_changed:

```
alter table texts add index (time_changed);
```

this could get rid of `Using temporary` and `filesort`. But you need to define indexes for your query because the query plan show `Using where` instead of more healthy `Using index`.

---

**Updated**

Maybe the main culprit for the temporary/filesort is the order of the join. It is not good practice to force the optimizer without a good reason, but you could try to force the join order to test if the temporary/filesort goes away. I have swapped the tables and added a `straight_join` clause:

```
SELECT straight_join
     t2.text_id
FROM
    texts AS t2,
    texts_to_categories AS t1
WHERE
    t1.category_id = 123 
    AND t2.text_id = t1.text_id
ORDER BY
    t2.time_changed DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Let me know what is the query plan of the previous query.

I don't think that temporary/filesort is a big deal for few hundred rows. I would let the optimizer do its job. I would be more worried to get a better tables schema. If it is feasible for you, I suggest the following changes to your schema.

For `texts_categories` your table permits NULL value for `text_id` and for `category_id`. So I would delete NULL values:

```
delete from texts_to_categories  where category_id is NULL or text_id is NULL;

alter table texts_to_categories
change category_id category_id int unsigned not null,
change text_id text_id int unsigned not null;
```

Next if you don't need `texts_categories.id` column, I would get rid of it, and I would reorganize indexes:

```
alter table texts_to_categories
drop column id,
add primary key category_text (category_id, text_id),
drop index text_id,
drop index category_id,
add index text_id;
```

For table `texts` I will try `time_changed` column to do not permit null values:

```
update texts_bck 
set time_changed = '2010-01-01' -- some default
where time_changed is NULL;


alter table texts
change column time_changed time_changed datetime not null 
default current_timestamp;
```

I hope this is of help.